# How to verify if TortoiseHg repository is healthy

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg

We are moving one of our projects from Code Co-op to TortoiseHg (4.0.1).  Today, we got everything up and running.  Below is a screen capture of the Central Repository state.

[image]

I am worried about the graph for the central repository here.  When I tested the rollout of this setup previously, I do not recall the graph splitting like this.  (Rev 1 and 1+ are linked, and 0 and 2 through 5 are linked).

The only difference that occurred this time is the use of DropBox to host the CP.  We went in there and added some ignored files (Desktop.ini and a few dropbox config files).  Doing this caused it to create a .hgignore file for the central repo which was then committed.

Our local clones of the repo (that we each use to do our own work in) have their own .hgignore files as well, with different entries.

I am a little unnerved that the graphs no longer touch.  I am very new to this revision control system and would appreciate some guidance on what I did wrong here (if anything) and how to correct it before we get into new serious development.  I tried a revert all on Rev 1, but the end effect was nothing.  At that point, I figured I'd seek a higher power.  Thanks!

Comment: what does hg verify tell you?
Generally such graph is possible if you make two commits based on rev -1 (or null) or pull in an independent repository. It's nothing which is bad by itself, but most often it is unwanted. If you can merge the revisions 1+ and 5 and are happy with the result that's probably the easiest solution - if you don't miss anything

Comment: I agree with what planetmaker said. However, it seems unusual that each clone uses different `.hgignore`. That's bound to result in some conflicts at some point when merging.

Comment: It is unusual, and should not be happening again.  Rookie mistake. Thank you for your help. hg verify did not find any issue.  But, merging 1+ and 5 did the trick.  Its a large project and it chewed on it for a while, but eventually all it did was make me merge the .hgignore files